# Обработка ошибок при получении почты.

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Добрый день, уважаемые программисты! При получении почты изредка, но возникает ошибка со следующим текстом:

```
Access violation at address 004F34D7 in module 'Project1.exe'. Read of address 05580000
```

Понятия не имею  в чем причина и как бороться с данной ошибкой. При возможности прошу помочь советом, либо литературой.

Почту получаю следующим образом:

```
IdPOP31.Host:='хост';                        
  IdPOP31.Port:=110;    
  IdPOP31.Username:='имя';  
  IdPOP31.Password:='пароль';                    
  IdMessage1.Clear;                                          
  IdPOP31.Connect;                                            
  IdMessage1.CharSet:='utf-8';
  IdMessage1.Clear;                                           
  Application.ProcessMessages;
  lb_letters.Clear;
  j:=IdPOP31.CheckMessages;
  if j>0
  then for i:=j downto 1 do
  begin
    IdMessage1.Clear;                                         
    IdPOP31.RetrieveHeader(i, IdMessage1);
    if AnsiCompareText(IdMessage1.From.Address,'webmaster@mark-itt.ru')=0
    then begin
      IdPOP31.Retrieve(i, IdMessage1);
      IdPOP31.Delete(i);
      Application.ProcessMessages;
    end else Panel1.Caption:=IdMessage1.From.Address;
    p_attachment.Caption:=IntToStr(i)+'/'+IntToStr(j);
  end;
  IdPOP31.Disconnect;
```

Ошибка возникает в модуле IdGlobal в строке:

```
Function  PosIdx (const ASubStr,AStr: AnsiString; AStartPos: Cardinal): Cardinal;
...
if lpS^ = LChar then begin
...
```

Comment: Наивный вопрос - вы понимаете что происходит в первом фрагменте кода?  
И второй, не менее наивный, - пробовали выполнить код по шагам?

Comment: Видимо причина в том, что индексы писем меняются из-за того, что ты их удаляешь.
если просто получать письма не удаляя, думаю такой ошибки не возникает

Comment: @NMD Замечание имеет место. Благодарю.